# Python localhost server

Tags: python, django

Whenever I use `python manage.py runserver` on Windows PowerShell it causes Python to crash: "Python has stopped working" window pops up. Any idea why?
I've tried rebooting, which causes a different type of error:

> python.exe: can't open file '.\maanage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I created another project and tried `runserver` and again it caused the first error. All installation commands ran smoothly, but why am I facing this error?

Comment: I'd say the problem is fairly obvious: python.exe: can't open file '.\maanage.py. the file manage.py is spelled `manage.py`. Look at the error you're given, sometimes they are helpful

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're spelling the file name correctly. 
maanage.py != manage.py

Comment: that I get but what about the python has stopped working error?